# How to do Calculation after subtotal... Discount, Vat and Total

Tags: javascript, angular

Calculation till Subtotal is perfect, and discount and VAT from drop-down calculation is perfect but Total is not showing in the end... I want these drop-down selection should be in input textbox where i will add by myself the Discount and VAT values and it will calculate all values onchange and show in Total.

```
    $scope.AddNewRow = function () {
        $scope.InvoiceCart.push({ ProductId: null, CategoryName: '', UnitPrice: 0, Quantity: 1, LineTotal: 0 });
    }
    $scope.SetValueOfProduct = function (productId) {
        var dataObj = $filter('filter')($scope.ProductList, { ProductId: parseInt(productId) })[0];
        const index = $scope.InvoiceCart.findIndex((x) => x.ProductId === productId);
        $scope.InvoiceCart[index].CategoryName = dataObj.CategoryName;
        $scope.InvoiceCart[index].UnitPrice = dataObj.SalesPrice;
        $scope.InvoiceCart[index].LineTotal = $scope.InvoiceCart[index].UnitPrice * $scope.InvoiceCart[index].Quantity;
    }
    $scope.OnChangeLineTotalSet = function (productId) {
        const index = $scope.InvoiceCart.findIndex((x) => x.ProductId === productId);
        $scope.InvoiceCart[index].LineTotal = $scope.InvoiceCart[index].UnitPrice * $scope.InvoiceCart[index].Quantity;
    }
    $scope.SubTotalCalculation = function () {
        $scope.Sale.Subtotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.InvoiceCart.length; i++) {
            $scope.Sale.Subtotal = $scope.Sale.Subtotal + $scope.InvoiceCart[i].LineTotal;
        }
    }
    $scope.CalculateDiscount = function () {
        $scope.Sale.DiscountAmount = ($scope.Sale.Subtotal * $scope.Sale.DiscountParcentage) / 100;
    }
    $scope.CalculateVat = function () {
        $scope.Sale.VatAmount = (($scope.Sale.Subtotal - $scope.Sale.DiscountAmount) * $scope.Sale.VatParcentage) / 100;
        $scope.Sale.TotalAmount = ($scope.Sale.Subtotal - $scope.Sale.DiscountAmount) + $scope.Sale.VatAmount;
        //$scope.Sale.TotalAmout = ($scope.Sale.Subtotal - $scope.Sale.DiscountAmount) + $scope.Sale.VatAmount;
    }
    $scope.RowDelete = function (index) {
        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.InvoiceCart.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $scope.SubTotalCalculation();
    }
    $scope.SaveInvoice = function () {
        $scope.Sale.OrderNo = $("#OrderNo").val();
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            sale: $scope.Sale, salesDetails: $scope.InvoiceCart
        });
        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/SaveInvoiceSale",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsSuccess == true) {

                    //Reset();
                    alert("Save Success!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Save failed!");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML CODE

```
        </div>

        <div class="table-responsive-sm">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="center">#</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Category</th>

                        <th class="right">Unit Cost</th>
                        <th class="center">Qty</th>
                        <th class="right">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="cart in InvoiceCart">
                        <td class="center">{{$index+1}}</td>
                        <td class="left strong">
                            <select ng-model="cart.ProductId" ng-click="SetValueOfProduct(cart.ProductId);SubTotalCalculation();">
                                <option>--Select--</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="product in ProductList" value="{{product.ProductId}}">{{product.Name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="left">{{cart.CategoryName}}</td>

                        <td class="right"><input ng-model="cart.UnitPrice" value="{{cart.UnitPrice}}" /></td>
                        <td class="center"><input class="BorderLess" ng-model="cart.Quantity" ng-change="OnChangeLineTotalSet(cart.ProductId);SubTotalCalculation();" value="1" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
                        <td class="right"><input value={{cart.Quantity*cart.UnitPrice}} ng-model="cart.LineTotal" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#" ng-click="RowDelete($index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" ng-click="AddNewRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 ml-auto">
                <table class="table table-clear">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">
                                <strong>Subtotal</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="right">${{Sale.Subtotal}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">
                                <strong>
                                    Discount
                                    <select ng-model="Sale.DiscountParcentage" ng-click="CalculateDiscount()">
                                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                        <option value="10">10%</option>
                                        <option value="20">20%</option>
                                        <option value="30">30%</option>
                                    </select>
                                </strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="right">${{Sale.DiscountAmount}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">
                                <strong>
                                    VAT
                                    <select ng-model="Sale.VatParcentage" ng-click="CalculateVat()">
                                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                        <option value="10">10%</option>
                                        <option value="20">20%</option>
                                        <option value="30">30%</option>
                                    </select>
                                </strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="right">${{Sale.VatAmount}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">
                                <strong>Total</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="right" value="${{Sale.TotalAmount}}">
                                <strong></strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take care not to add irrelevant tags to your question.